# JPA Hibernate duas Entidades com mesmo Nome, salvando sempre na mesma entidade

Tags: mysql, swing, jpa

Tenho uma `jCombobox` onde são carregadas todas as `entidades` alunos.
Acontece de ter duas entidades com o mesmo nome (dois alunos Rodrigo Silva por exemplo). As duas são carregadas na `combo`.

Ao `gravar` os dados no `banco`, não importa qual das duas `entidades` listadas com o mesmo nome eu escolha, é gravado sempre para a de `id` mais baixo (neste caso o `id` 1).
O que estou fazendo errado, como posso resolver isto?

```
public T save(T t) throws Exception {
EntityManager em = getEm();
try {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if (t.getId() == null) {
        em.persist(t);

    } else {
        if (em.contains(t)) {
            if (em.find(t.getClass(), t.getId()) == null) {
                throw new Exception("Erro");
            }
        }
        t = em.merge(t);

    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
} finally {
    em.close();
}
return t;
```

}

```
    ocorrencia.setAluno((Aluno) jCAluno.getSelectedItem());
    OcorrenciaDao oc = new OcorrenciaDao();
    oc.save(ocorrencia);
```

Método que popula a `combo`:

```
  public void loadComboAluno() {
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.jCAluno);
    AlunoDao alunoDao = new AlunoDao();
    List<Aluno> listaAlunos = alunoDao.consultarAlunos();
    for (Aluno set : listaAlunos) {
        jCAluno.addItem(set);
    }
}
```

Método da consulta:

```
   public List<Aluno> consultarAlunos() {
    EntityManager em = getEm();
    List<Aluno> listaAlunos;
    try {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Aluno.findAll");
        listaAlunos = q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        listaAlunos = new ArrayList<>();

    } finally {
        em.close();

    }
    return listaAlunos;

}
```

Classe Aluno:

```
    @Entity
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Aluno.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Aluno c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Aluno.findByAlunoId", query = "SELECT c FROM Aluno c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Aluno.findByAlunoNome", query = "SELECT c FROM Aluno c WHERE c.nome = :nome")})
public class Aluno implements EntidadeBase, Serializable {

    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idAluno")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "nomeAluno")
    private String nome;
```

Comment: Como está sua classe aluno? Como você está populando o jcombobox com alunos?

Comment: Como você chama o método `getId` se `t` é genérico?

Comment: @renan se t tiver algum tipo de "contrato" na assinatura desta classe que tenha esse método, acho que isso funciona.

Comment: Adicionei mais trechos de código para ver se ajuda esclarecer.

Comment: Após algum tempo percebi que o que acontece é que o `selectedItem` muda para o primeiro da lista, após o click, e por isso faz o `insert` sempre para a mesma entidade. Alguém já teve este problema?